# Get keys from HashMap in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, java-6

I have a Hashmap in Java like this:

```
private Map<String, Integer> team1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then I fill it like this:

```
team1.put("United", 5);
```

How can I get the keys?  Something like: `team1.getKey()` to return "United".

Comment: What do you expect `team1.getKey()` to return if: (1) the map is empty, or (2) if it contains multiple keys?

Comment: `int` should be used for single ones like this.

Answer (score 386, accepted):

A `HashMap` contains more than one key. You can use `keySet()` to get the set of all keys.

```
team1.put("foo", 1);
team1.put("bar", 2);
```

will store `1` with key `"foo"` and `2` with key `"bar"`. To iterate over all the keys:

```
for ( String key : team1.keySet() ) {
    System.out.println( key );
}
```

will print `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

Comment: But in this case i only have one key for each value. It is not possible to write anything like team1.getKey()?

Comment: No you have a map with one element. But it's a map: a structure that can contain more than one element.

Comment: What's the point of a Map with a single key? Create a class with a key field and a value field.

Comment: If you want to store all keys in array list : `List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(mLoginMap.keySet());`

Answer (score 72):

This is doable, at least in theory, **if** you know the index:

```
System.out.println(team1.keySet().toArray()[0]);
```

`keySet()` returns a set, so you convert the set to an array.

The problem, of course, is that a set doesn't promise to keep your order.  If you only have one item in your HashMap, you're good, but if you have more than that, it's best to loop over the map, as other answers have done.

Comment: This is helpful in a unit testing scenario where you have full control over the contents of your `HashMap`.  Good show.

Comment: Nothing about knowing the index in the question.

Comment: this is really slow and memory inefficient. probably not what you want to do for most cases, including the question

Answer (score 29):

Check this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

(Use `java.util.Objects.equals` because HashMap can contain `null`)

Using JDK8+

```
/**
 * Find any key matching a value.
 *
 * @param value The value to be matched. Can be null.
 * @return Any key matching the value in the team.
 */
private Optional<String> findKey(Integer value){
    return team1
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getValue(), value))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .findAny();
}

/**
 * Find all keys matching a value.
 *
 * @param value The value to be matched. Can be null.
 * @return all keys matching the value in the team.
 */
private List<String> findKeys(Integer value){
    return team1
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getValue(), value))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

More "generic" and as safe as possible

```
/**
 * Find any key matching the value, in the given map.
 *
 * @param mapOrNull Any map, null is considered a valid value.
 * @param value     The value to be searched.
 * @param <K>       Type of the key.
 * @param <T>       Type of the value.
 * @return An optional containing a key, if found.
 */
public static <K, T> Optional<K> findKey(Map<K, T> mapOrNull, T value) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(mapOrNull).flatMap(map -> map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getValue(), value))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .findAny());
}
```

Or if you are on JDK7.

```
private String findKey(Integer value){
    for(String key : team1.keySet()){
        if(Objects.equals(team1.get(key), value)){
            return key; //return the first found
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private List<String> findKeys(Integer value){
   List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(String key : team1.keySet()){
        if(Objects.equals(team1.get(key), value)){
             keys.add(key);
      }
   }
   return keys;
}
```

Comment: But what happens if several keys map to the same value? you should be returning a list of keys instead

Answer (score 7):

You can retrieve all of the `Map`'s keys using the method [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29). Now, if what you need is to get a *key* given its *value*, that's an entirely different matter and `Map` won't help you there; you'd need a specialized data structure, like [`BidiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html) (a map that allows bidirectional lookup between key and values) from Apache's [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) - also be aware that several different keys could be mapped to the same value.

Answer (score 5):

Use functional operation for faster iteration.

```
team1.keySet().forEach((key) -> {
      System.out.println(key);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

foreach can be used too.

```
team1.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key));
```

Answer (score 2):

As you would like to get argument (`United`) for which value is given (`5`) you might also consider using bidirectional map (e.g. provided by Guava: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
private Map<String, Integer> _map= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> itr=  _map.entrySet().iterator();
                //please check 
                while(itr.hasNext())
                {
                    System.out.println("key of : "+itr.next().getKey()+" value of      Map"+itr.next().getValue());
                }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Clearly you haven't tried it.  Calling `next()` twice in the loop means that you will print the odd-numbered keys along with the even-numbered values.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need something simple and more of a verification.

```
public String getKey(String key)
{
    if(map.containsKey(key)
    {
        return key;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can search for any key.

```
System.out.println( "Does this key exist? : " + getKey("United") );
```

Comment: This method is totally redundant.

Answer (score 1):

To get keys in HashMap, We have keySet() method which is present in `java.util.Hashmap` package.
ex :

```java
Map<String,String> map = new Hashmap<String,String>();
map.put("key1","value1");
map.put("key2","value2");

// Now to get keys we can use keySet() on map object
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
```

Now **keys** will have your all keys available in map.
ex: [key1,key2]

Comment: `java,util.HashMap` is a class, not a package, and there is nothing here that wasn't here five years ago.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be, if you know the key position, convert the keys into an String array and return the value in the position:

```
public String getKey(int pos, Map map) {
    String[] keys = (String[]) map.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);

    return keys[pos];
}
```

Comment: Nothing about knowing the index in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple program:

```
public class HashMapGetKey {

public static void main(String args[]) {

      // create hash map

       HashMap map = new HashMap();

      // populate hash map

      map.put(1, "one");
      map.put(2, "two");
      map.put(3, "three");
      map.put(4, "four");

      // get keyset value from map

Set keyset=map.keySet();

      // check key set values

      System.out.println("Key set values are: " + keyset);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyHashMapKeys {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //add key-value pair to hashmap
        hm.put("first", "FIRST INSERTED");
        hm.put("second", "SECOND INSERTED");
        hm.put("third","THIRD INSERTED");
        System.out.println(hm);
        Set<String> keys = hm.keySet();
        for(String key: keys){
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Merely copies existing answers.  -1

Answer (score -2):

What I'll do which is very simple but waste memory is to map the values with a key and do the oposite to map the keys with a value making this:

`private Map<Object, Object> team1 = new HashMap<Object, Object>();`

it's important that you use `<Object, Object>` so you can map `keys:Value` and `Value:Keys` like this

`team1.put("United", 5);`

`team1.put(5, "United");`

So if you use  `team1.get("United") = 5` and `team1.get(5) = "United"`

But if you use some specific method on one of the objects in the pairs I'll be better if you make another map:

`private Map<String, Integer> team1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

`private Map<Integer, String> team1Keys = new HashMap<Integer, String>();`

and then

`team1.put("United", 5);`

`team1Keys.put(5, "United");`

and remember, keep it simple ;)

Answer (score -2):

To get **Key** and its **value**

e.g

```
private Map<String, Integer> team1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  team1.put("United", 5);
  team1.put("Barcelona", 6);
    for (String key:team1.keySet()){
                     System.out.println("Key:" + key +" Value:" + team1.get(key)+" Count:"+Collections.frequency(team1, key));// Get Key and value and count
                }
```

**Will print:** Key: United Value:5 
                Key: Barcelona Value:6