# How to get the first key of a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following `HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();`

How can i get the first key without iterating over it like this:

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    it.remove(); 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get keys from HashMap in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462819/get-keys-from-hashmap-in-java)

Comment: What is `the first key`? The smallest one? The first one you inserted? The first one you get when iterating over the key set?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the value of the "first" key, you can use it

```
map.get(map.keySet().toArray()[0]);
```

### In Java8,

You can use stream. For **TreeMap/LinkedHashMap**, where ordering is significant, you can write

```
map.entrySet().stream().findFirst();
```

For **HashMap**, there is no order, so `findAny()` might return a different result on different calls

```
map.entrySet().stream().findAny();
```

Answer (score 8):

Since your question is not very specific about what you consider the "first key" I will just list a few options.

**Just the first one in the key set**

```
String firstKey = map.keySet().iterator().next();
```

But no idea what information that provides you.

**The smallest key**

```
String firstKey = map.keySet().stream().min(String::compareTo).get();
```

**The key of the smallest value**

```
String firstKey = map.entrySet().stream().min((a,b) -> a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue())).get().getKey();
```

**The first inserted key**

This does not work with a regular `HashMap` because it does not preserve the ordering. Use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
String firstKey = map.keySet().iterator().next();
```

Answer (score 5):

### if you use Java 8,

```
map.entrySet().stream().findFirst().get().getKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Double> map=new HashMap<>();
Map.Entry<String, Double> entry=map.entrySet().iterator().next();
 String key= entry.getKey();
```

But HashMap doesn't maintain insertion order. You can use **LinkedHashMap** instead of HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `it.next()` once, be sure the iterator is just in the first position.

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry firstEntry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the `Map` and expect to iterate over it in the order you inserted entries, you should use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

This is assuming "first key" means the first one you inserted. Then you can iterate over it in the order you inserted entries, or if you just want the first key like you said, you can call `map.keySet().toArray()[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap, It maintains the order of insertion when calling keySet().

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)